# Strange IMAP folder

Tags: macos, mail.app, imap

I am using an IMAP email account on several OS X and iOS devices.

On one single OS X machine I have a greyed-out Drafts folder with some *strange* subfolders:

[image]

This is only happening on this particular machine (El Capitan). On other Macs with the same system I see, as expected:

[image]

Is there a way to refresh the IMAP folders?

**Edit**

The subfolders shown by *Drafts* are not empty: they are a subset of the folders I have on the top level (i.e., Sent Messages).

The option to choose a folder as *Drafts* is not present:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The folders that should not be there are empty, correct?
Select the Drafts-Home-Drafts mailbox, in menu point Mailbox, choose "use this mailbox as" and select "Drafts".
Do such also for the mailboxes under Drafts-Home that you want gone, i.e. "Drafts-Home-Deleted Messages" to Deleted Messages, and so on. Then do it for "Drafts-Home".
Just deleting them might not work.

Comment: Thanks: the folders are not empty and the option is not there ...